# JCIP @GuardedBy warning in [Java theory and practice: Managing volatility] Article code

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I tried to implement this class as described at [Java theory and practice: Managing volatility](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp06197/index.html), section: **Pattern #5: The cheap read-write lock trick**

```
@ThreadSafe
public class CheesyCounter {
    // Employs the cheap read-write lock trick
    // All mutative operations MUST be done with the 'this' lock held
    @GuardedBy("this") private volatile int value;

    public int getValue() { return value; }

    public synchronized int increment() {
        return value++;
    }
}
```

However, I get this *warning*:

[image]

could someone explain what is going on? Is the code incorrect?

Comment: `getValue` is not `synchronized` on "this" and that's the reported issue, the IDE inspection is probably not aware of the "trick"

Comment: got it.. code is fine, inspection is not smart enough

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167633